# Flutter. Path scaling

Tags: flutter

How can I change the size of path in this section of code? When drawing, the path goes beyond the phone screen. 
I should not have access to drawing the paths themselves.

```
Path path = getPath();  //the path is given dynamically

canvas.drawPath(
  path,
  Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeWidth = 2.0);
```

I tried to use the method `path.transform`. But the path is not transformed correctly.

Comment: you could use provide size as `Path path = getPath(size);` so that the generated path is created based on size, assuming you are generating the path yourself.

Comment: @Doc yes, but I should not interfere with the logic of this method. This method remains as it is.

Comment: so you cannot edit the generated path but want it to scale to lets say `Size size`. Right?

Comment: @Doc yes, I want this path to fit in the screen

Comment: complete code posted for screen size scaling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for adjustment is as follows.

```
main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: SO()));

class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: SOP(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SOP extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path p = getPath();

    Rect b = p.getBounds();
    var path_width = b.width;
    var path_height = b.height;
    var screen_width = size.width;
    var screen_height = size.height;
    var x_scale = screen_width / path_width;
    var y_scale = screen_height / path_height;

    //UNCOMMENT the following line to see the scaling effect
//    canvas.scale(x_scale, y_scale);

    canvas.drawPath(p, Paint()..color = Colors.red);
  }

  Path getPath() {
    Path p = Path();
    double w = 100;
    double h = 100;
    p.moveTo(0, 0);
    p.lineTo(0, h);
    p.lineTo(w, h);
    p.lineTo(w, 0);
    p.close();
    return p;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Uncomment the scaling line to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Doc proposed a solution by scaling the canvas.
Another way would be to scale the path by using the transform method :

```
var scalingMatrix = Float64List.fromList(
    [size.width, 0, 0, 0,
    0, size.height, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1]);
path = path.transform(scalingMatrix);
```

Comment: instead of size.width and height. its a scale factor. 1 mean not scale, 1 > scale down, big than 1 is scaling up.